# Angularjs Go back button not working when using a url with a query string

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, router

Here is my ui-router which is working just fine :

```
ngModule.config(['$stateProvider',
    function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('homepage', {
                url: '',
                templateUrl: '/partials/homepage/'
            })
            .state('item', {
                url: '/item/:item_id',
                templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
                    return '/partials/item/' + $stateParams.item_id + '/';
                }
            })
            .state('search', {
                url: '/search/?q',
                templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
                    return '/partials/search/?q=' + $stateParams.q;
                }
            });
    }]);
```

The routing is working fine as well. The only issue happens with the search state. The browser's go back button doesn't work in that case. The only different with the 2 before come from the string query. How can I fix the back button to have it working a string query ?

Comment: Why do you want to set a dynamic templateUrl in the first place?

Comment: Is that something to avoid ? It is just a classic way of doing stuff if you want to use django and angularjs together.

Comment: Check this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069105/how-to-get-the-previous-state-with-params-using-ui-router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069105/how-to-get-the-previous-state-with-params-using-ui-router)